# Matplotlib basemap nightshade, is a point in the dark

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working on plotting lat, lon points on a map and I want to figure out if the points are in the dark or light. I have code running that plots the map and the shading using [`nightshade()`](http://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/utilities.html#nightshade), what I don't know how to do if figure out if the point is in the dark or in the light.

It strikes me that the regions in the `matplotlib.contour.QuadContourSet` object returned by nightshade, should make it possible to tell if a point is shaded grey or white, but I cannot figure out how. Anyone have thoughts, a working example is below.

The `matplotlib.contour.QuadContourSet` has a `.collections` which returns a list of 3 `mcoll.PathCollection` objects so maybe the question is how to figure out if a point is inside a `PathCollection`.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, shiftgrid, cm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8])
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-145.5,llcrnrlat=1.,urcrnrlon=-2.566,urcrnrlat=46.352,\
            rsphere=(6378137.00,6356752.3142),\
            resolution='l',area_thresh=1000.,projection='lcc',\
            lat_1=50.,lon_0=-107.,ax=ax)
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries()
m.drawstates()
parallels = np.arange(0.,80,20.)
m.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[1,0,0,1])
meridians = np.arange(10.,360.,30.)
m.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[1,0,0,1])
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime(2014, 4, 1, 12)
CS=m.nightshade(date)

lats = [40, 40]
lons = [-120, -85]
x,y = m(lons, lats)

m.scatter(x, y, color='r', s=50)
ax.set_title(date.isoformat())

plt.show()
```

[image: Map with points, light dark]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry it took you three years to get an answer... Try this out.

It requires the `shapely` library, but assuming it's no big deal to install that, I think this should do the trick.

[image: image with Basemap]

Many thanks to this site for inspiration!

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99917/converting-matplotlib-contour-objects-to-shapely-objects

```
    from datetime import datetime
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, shiftgrid, cm
    from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point

    # set up basemap
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
    m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-145.5, llcrnrlat=1., urcrnrlon=-2.566, urcrnrlat=46.352,
                rsphere=(6378137.00, 6356752.3142),
                resolution='l', area_thresh=1000., projection='lcc',
                lat_1=50., lon_0=-107., ax=ax)
    m.drawcoastlines()
    m.drawcountries()
    m.drawstates()
    parallels = np.arange(0., 80, 20.)
    m.drawparallels(parallels, labels=[1, 0, 0, 1])
    meridians = np.arange(10., 360., 30.)
    m.drawmeridians(meridians, labels=[1, 0, 0, 1])
    date = datetime(2014, 4, 1, 12)
    ax.set_title(date.isoformat())

    # get the contour set of the nightshade
    cs = m.nightshade(date)    

    # get each polygon from the contour collection
    polys = []
    for i in range(len(cs.collections)):
        p = cs.collections[i]
        if p.get_paths() != []:
            p = p.get_paths()[0]
            v = p.vertices
            x = v[:, 0]
            y = v[:, 1]
            poly = Polygon([(i[0], i[1]) for i in zip(x, y)])
            polys.append(poly)

    # define your points
    lats = [40, 40]
    lons = [-120, -85]
    x, y = m(lons, lats)
    points = [Point(xi, yi) for xi, yi in zip(x, y)]

    # plot your points, red for dark green for light
    for point in points:
        in_shade = any([poly.contains(point) for poly in polys])
        if in_shade:
            m.scatter([point.x], [point.y], color='r', s=50)
        else:
            m.scatter([point.x], [point.y], color='g', s=50)

    plt.show()
```

EDIT:

As far as I can tell, Cartopy does not have the functionality we need built in.

In V0.17, we'd just need to add a little change to cartopy.feature.nightshade, on line 107, after we define `geom`, write `self.geom = geom`, and then we could use the geometry from the Nightshade class as we did using basemap.

However, since Cartopy still seems to be changing rapidly, I'll advise others not to go changing Cartopy's code, and I'll just copy it here (but all credit for that file except the one geom line goes to the original authors).

I also changed projections because LambertConformal() was giving me grief, and it wasn't relevant to this question.

`

```
# --- START nightshade.py ---
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function)

import datetime

import numpy as np
import shapely.geometry as sgeom

from cartopy.feature import ShapelyFeature
from cartopy import crs as ccrs


class Nightshade(ShapelyFeature):
    def __init__(self, date=None, delta=0.1, refraction=-0.83,
                 color="k", alpha=0.5, **kwargs):
        """
        Shade the darkside of the Earth, accounting for refraction.

        Parameters
        ----------
        date : datetime
            A UTC datetime object used to calculate the position of the sun.
            Default: datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        delta : float
            Stepsize in degrees to determine the resolution of the
            night polygon feature (``npts = 180 / delta``).
        refraction : float
            The adjustment in degrees due to refraction,
            thickness of the solar disc, elevation etc...

        Note
        ----
            Matplotlib keyword arguments can be used when drawing the feature.
            This allows standard Matplotlib control over aspects such as
            'color', 'alpha', etc.

        """
        if date is None:
            date = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

        # make sure date is UTC, or naive with respect to time zones
        if date.utcoffset():
            raise ValueError('datetime instance must be UTC, not {0}'.format(
                             date.tzname()))

        # Returns the Greenwich hour angle,
        # need longitude (opposite direction)
        lat, lon = _solar_position(date)
        pole_lon = lon
        if lat > 0:
            pole_lat = -90 + lat
            central_lon = 180
        else:
            pole_lat = 90 + lat
            central_lon = 0

        rotated_pole = ccrs.RotatedPole(pole_latitude=pole_lat,
                                        pole_longitude=pole_lon,
                                        central_rotated_longitude=central_lon)

        npts = int(180/delta)
        x = np.empty(npts*2)
        y = np.empty(npts*2)

        # Solve the equation for sunrise/sunset:
        # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_equation#Generalized_equation
        # NOTE: In the generalized equation on Wikipedia,
        #       delta == 0. in the rotated pole coordinate system.
        #       Therefore, the max/min latitude is +/- (90+refraction)

        # Fill latitudes up and then down
        y[:npts] = np.linspace(-(90+refraction), 90+refraction, npts)
        y[npts:] = y[:npts][::-1]

        # Solve the generalized equation for omega0, which is the
        # angle of sunrise/sunset from solar noon
        omega0 = np.rad2deg(np.arccos(np.sin(np.deg2rad(refraction)) /
                                      np.cos(np.deg2rad(y))))

        # Fill the longitude values from the offset for midnight.
        # This needs to be a closed loop to fill the polygon.
        # Negative longitudes
        x[:npts] = -(180 - omega0[:npts])
        # Positive longitudes
        x[npts:] = 180 - omega0[npts:]

        kwargs.setdefault('facecolor', color)
        kwargs.setdefault('alpha', alpha)

        geom = sgeom.Polygon(np.column_stack((x, y)))
        self.geom = geom
        return super(Nightshade, self).__init__(
            [geom], rotated_pole, **kwargs)


def _julian_day(date):
    """
    Calculate the Julian day from an input datetime.

    Parameters
    ----------
    date
        A UTC datetime object.

    Note
    ----
    Algorithm implemented following equations from Chapter 3 (Algorithm 14):
    Vallado, David 'Fundamentals of Astrodynamics and Applications', (2007)

    Julian day epoch is: noon on January 1, 4713 BC (proleptic Julian)
                         noon on November 24, 4714 BC (proleptic Gregorian)

    """
    year = date.year
    month = date.month
    day = date.day
    hour = date.hour
    minute = date.minute
    second = date.second

    # January/February correspond to months 13/14 respectively
    # for the constants to work out properly
    if month < 3:
        month += 12
        year -= 1

    B = 2 - int(year/100) + int(int(year/100)/4)
    C = ((second/60 + minute)/60 + hour)/24

    JD = (int(365.25*(year + 4716)) + int(30.6001*(month+1)) +
          day + B - 1524.5 + C)
    return JD


def _solar_position(date):
    """
    Calculate the latitude and longitude point where the sun is
    directly overhead for the given date.

    Parameters
    ----------
    date
        A UTC datetime object.

    Returns
    -------
    (latitude, longitude) in degrees

    Note
    ----
    Algorithm implemented following equations from Chapter 5 (Algorithm 29):
    Vallado, David 'Fundamentals of Astrodynamics and Applications', (2007)

    """
    # NOTE: Constants are in degrees in the textbook,
    #       so we need to convert the values from deg2rad when taking sin/cos

    # Centuries from J2000
    T_UT1 = (_julian_day(date) - 2451545.0)/36525

    # solar longitude (deg)
    lambda_M_sun = (280.460 + 36000.771*T_UT1) % 360

    # solar anomaly (deg)
    M_sun = (357.5277233 + 35999.05034*T_UT1) % 360

    # ecliptic longitude
    lambda_ecliptic = (lambda_M_sun + 1.914666471*np.sin(np.deg2rad(M_sun)) +
                       0.019994643*np.sin(np.deg2rad(2*M_sun)))

    # obliquity of the ecliptic (epsilon in Vallado's notation)
    epsilon = 23.439291 - 0.0130042*T_UT1

    # declination of the sun
    delta_sun = np.rad2deg(np.arcsin(np.sin(np.deg2rad(epsilon)) *
                                     np.sin(np.deg2rad(lambda_ecliptic))))

    # Greenwich mean sidereal time (seconds)
    theta_GMST = (67310.54841 +
                  (876600*3600 + 8640184.812866)*T_UT1 +
                  0.093104*T_UT1**2 -
                  6.2e-6*T_UT1**3)
    # Convert to degrees
    theta_GMST = (theta_GMST % 86400)/240

    # Right ascension calculations
    numerator = (np.cos(np.deg2rad(epsilon)) *
                 np.sin(np.deg2rad(lambda_ecliptic)) /
                 np.cos(np.deg2rad(delta_sun)))
    denominator = (np.cos(np.deg2rad(lambda_ecliptic)) /
                   np.cos(np.deg2rad(delta_sun)))

    alpha_sun = np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(numerator, denominator))

    # longitude is opposite of Greenwich Hour Angle (GHA)
    # GHA == theta_GMST - alpha_sun
    lon = -(theta_GMST-alpha_sun)
    if lon < -180:
        lon += 360

    return (delta_sun, lon)

# --- END COPIED CODE FROM nightshade.py ---

"""our code, formatted so you could use it as a separate module
if you include an "import nightshade" line"""
import datetime
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Point

import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cf

# pick a date
date = datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 1, 12)

# set up map
proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()
ax = plt.axes(projection=proj)
ax.set_extent([-145, -60, 0, 90], crs=proj)
ax.stock_img()
ax.gridlines()
ax.coastlines()
ax.set_title(date.isoformat())
# I would add states and other features here but Cartopy's links to
# naturalearth data seem to be broken for me... That's another issue though!
ns = Nightshade(date, alpha=0.6)
ax.add_feature(ns)
# This is only one polygon to deal with, nicer than basemap's version!
ns_poly = ns.geom  # this is the polygon that is the lit-up area

# define your points
lats = [40, 40]
lons = [-120, -85]

# plot your points, red for dark green for light
for lon, lat in zip(lons, lats):
    in_sun = ns_poly.contains(Point(lon, lat))
    if in_sun:
        ax.scatter([lon], [lat], color='g', s=50, transform=proj)
    else:
        ax.scatter([lon], [lat], color='r', s=50, transform=proj)

plt.show()
```

`
[image: image with Cartopy, using different projection]

Comment: Thanks, that is a nice answer. It seems that also since the question was asked that basemap has been deprecated in favor of cartopy.

Comment: That's true, though Cartopy isn't as well-suited to deal with this problem out of the box (as far as I can tell, I haven't fully switched to Cartopy yet). Hopefully the edit is useful to you.